# Understanding generics and Func arguments

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I would not be surprised if this has been answered somewhere, the problem is I am not sure how to phrase a search to find what I need.  The things I have already found have either been too simplistic to be usable or poorly explained such that I cannot translate it into my own project.  I had no formal instruction with event handlers, delegates, and the like (heck, I didn't even learn about Entity-Component Systems--or other design patterns--until long after I graduated college and was already employed as a programmer, and even then it wasn't something I learned at, or for, my job).

Essentially what I want to know is, what does the definition of Array.Sort<T>(T[] array, Comparison<T> comparison) **look** like?

There's clearly some kind of generalization going on, as myCompareDelegate(...) takes two arguments of **any** type.  In almost everything I've found relating to Func arguments, a Func<> parameter requires explicitly declared types, with the exception of some sample code using an operator I am unfamiliar with:

```
SomeUtility(arg => new MyType());
public void SomeUtility<T>(Func<object, T> converter) {
    var myType = converter("foo");
}
```

It **compiles** but I have no idea what it **does** and as such, I do not know how to utilize it to create code that will run or do what I want to do.

My goal here is to be able to create an event system (yes, I'm aware that C# has an event system built in, but again, all the sample code I've seen is either simplified to the point of uselessness--listeners contained in the same class as the dispatcher--or complicated and unexplained).  I want the following to be true:

1. a single function to register an event listener (for any Type of event and its subtypes)
2. a single function to dispatch an event (calling only the relevant listeners)
3. to be able to create new event types without having to modify the functions for registration and handling (no explicit types in the dispatcher beyond the base event class) provided the new event type extends the allowable event type (i.e. an Entity will only dispatch EntityEvents not WorldEvents).

I have a system that works currently, but it requires that all my handlers pass through a single "onEvent" function which takes a base event object and figures out what it's actual type is, passing that off to the true handler.

Eg:

```
//Entity implements IEventDispatcher
public SomeConstructor(Entity ent) {
    //public delegate void EventListener(EventBase eventData); is declared
    //in the IEventDispatcher interface.
    ent.attachEvent(typeof(EntityEventPreRender),  new EventListener(onEvent));
    ent.attachEvent(typeof(EntityEventPostRender),  new EventListener(onEvent));
}
//EntityEventPreRender extends EntityEventRender extends EntityEvent extends EventBase
//EntityEventPostRender extends EntityEventRender extends EntityEvent extends EventBase
public void onEvent(EventBase data) {
    if(data is EntityEventPreRender)
        onPre((EntityEventPreRender)data);
    if(data is EntityEventPostRender)
        onPost((EntityEventPostRender)data);
}
public void onPre(EntityEventPreRender evt) {}
public void onPost(EntityEventPostRender evt) {}
```

attachEvent() here is a function that takes a Type (used as a HashMap key) and a Delegate and stores it in a list (the HashMap value).  Dispatching the event just needs to pass the EventData object, which is queried for its type (via evt.GetType()) to retrieve the list of listeners, then invoking them: listItem(evt)

But I'd rather be able to just do this:

```
public SomeConstructor(Entity ent) {
    ent.attachEvent(onPre);
    ent.attachEvent(onPost);
}
public void onPre(EntityEventPreRender evt) {}
public void onPost(EntityEventPostRender evt) {}
```

But I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do this because I do not know how to declare the attachEvent() function to take a generic function parameter the way Array.Sort<T>(T[] array, Comparison<T> comparison) does.  I get the error:

> "The type arguments for method doSomething<T>(SomeClass.Thing<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like the following:

```
public  static  class   PubSub<TMessage>
{
    private static  List
                    <
                        Action
                        <
                            TMessage
                        >
                    >                   listeners   = new List<Action<TMessage>>();

    public  static  void                Listen(Action<TMessage> listener)
    {
        if (listener != null)   listeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public  static  void                Unlisten(Action<TMessage> listener)
    {
        if (listeners.Contains(listener))   listeners.Remove(listener);
    }

    public  static  void                Broadcast(TMessage message)
    {
        foreach(var listener in listeners)  listener(message);
    }

}
```

In the above code, using PubSub and specifying a type for TMessage creates a new static class in memory with its own memory space allocated for storing a separate list of listeners.  The compiler will ensure that only the substituted type for TMessage and its subclasses will be allowed in that list, provided you consistently use the base type as the type argument for the TMessage type parameter.

You would then use it like so:

```
public  class   SomeMessageType
{
    public  int     SomeId;
    public  string  SomeDescription;
}

public  class   SomePublisher
{

    public  void    DoSomethingCool(string description)
    {
        var randomizer  = new Random();
        ...
        PubSub<SomeMessageType>.Broadcast(new SomeMessageType(){SomeId = randomizer.Next(), SomeDescription = description});
    }

}

public  class   SomeListener
{

    static                  SomeListener()
    {
        PubSub<SomeMessageType>.Listen(SomeMessageEvent);
    }

    private static  void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeMessageType message)
    {
        // do something with the message
    }

}
```

If you then create another class SomeOtherMessageType which does not inherit from SomeMessageType and make similar calls to it, it will only broadcast to listeners of that specific type.

EDITED:

Here is a full proof of concept that compiles that you can run in a console app to allay any remaining concerns you may have over efficacy of this technique.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestPubSub
{


    public  class   Program
    {

        public  static  void    Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.startListeners();

            Program.sendTestMessages();

            Program.stopConsoleFromExitingImmediately();
        }

        private static  void    startListeners()
        {
            SomeListener.Listen();
            SomeOtherListener1.Listen();
            SomeOtherListener2.Listen();
        }

        private static  void    sendTestMessages()
        {
            var publisher1  = new SomePublisher();
            var publisher2  = new SomeOtherPublisher();

            publisher1.DoSomethingCool("Hello world");
            publisher2.DoSomethingElse(DateTime.Now);
        }

        private static  void    stopConsoleFromExitingImmediately()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public  static  class   PubSub<TMessage>
    {
        private static  List
                        <
                            Action
                            <
                                TMessage
                            >
                        >                   listeners   = new List<Action<TMessage>>();

        public  static  void                Listen(Action<TMessage> listener)
        {
            if (listener != null)   listeners.Add(listener);
        }

        public  static  void                Unlisten(Action<TMessage> listener)
        {
            if (listeners.Contains(listener))   listeners.Remove(listener);
        }

        public  static  void                Broadcast(TMessage message)
        {
            foreach(var listener in listeners)  listener(message);
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeMessageType
    {
        public  int     SomeId;
        public  string  SomeDescription;
    }

    public  class   SomeOtherMessageType
    {
        public  DateTime    SomeDate;
        public  Double      SomeAmount;
    }

    public  class   SomePublisher
    {

        public  void    DoSomethingCool(string description)
        {
            var randomizer  = new Random();
            PubSub<SomeMessageType>.Broadcast(new SomeMessageType(){SomeId = randomizer.Next(), SomeDescription = description});
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeOtherPublisher
    {

        public  void    DoSomethingElse(DateTime when)
        {
            var randomizer  = new Random();
            PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>.Broadcast(new SomeOtherMessageType(){SomeAmount = randomizer.NextDouble(), SomeDate = when});
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeListener
    {

        public  static  void    Listen()
        {
            PubSub<SomeMessageType>.Listen(SomeMessageEvent);
        }

        private static  void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeMessageType message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attention! SomeMessageType receieved by SomeListener with\r\nid: {0}\r\ndescription: {1}\r\n", message.SomeId, message.SomeDescription);
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeOtherListener1
    {

        public  static  void    Listen()
        {
            PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>.Listen(SomeMessageEvent);
        }

        private static  void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeOtherMessageType message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Heads up! SomeOtherMessageType receieved by SomeOtherListener1 with\r\namount: {0}\r\ndate: {1}\r\n", message.SomeAmount, message.SomeDate);
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeOtherListener2
    {

        public  static  void    Listen()
        {
            PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>.Listen(SomeMessageEvent);
        }

        private static  void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeOtherMessageType message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yo! SomeOtherMessageType receieved by SomeOtherListener2 withr\namount: {0}\r\ndate: {1}\r\n", message.SomeAmount, message.SomeDate);
        }

    }

}
```

EDITED AGAIN (Alternate proof of concept using an instance based pubs):

Here is a proof of concept using an instance based PubSub.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestPubSub
{


    public  class   Program
    {

        private static  PubSub<SomeMessageType>         pubSub1     = new PubSub<SomeMessageType>();
        private static  PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>    pubSub2     = new PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>();
        private static  SomeListener                    listener1   = new SomeListener();
        private static  SomeOtherListener1              listener2   = new SomeOtherListener1();
        private static  SomeOtherListener2              listener3   = new SomeOtherListener2();

        public  static  void                Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.startListeners();

            Program.sendTestMessages();

            Program.stopConsoleFromExitingImmediately();
        }

        private static  void    startListeners()
        {
            Program.listener1.Listen(Program.pubSub1);
            Program.listener2.Listen(Program.pubSub2);
            Program.listener3.Listen(Program.pubSub2);
        }

        private static  void    sendTestMessages()
        {
            var publisher1  = new SomePublisher(Program.pubSub1);
            var publisher2  = new SomeOtherPublisher(Program.pubSub2);

            publisher1.DoSomethingCool("Hello world");
            publisher2.DoSomethingElse(DateTime.Now);
        }

        private static  void    stopConsoleFromExitingImmediately()
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public  class   PubSub<TMessage>
    {
        private List
                <
                    Action
                    <
                        TMessage
                    >
                >                   listeners   = new List<Action<TMessage>>();

        public  void                Listen(Action<TMessage> listener)
        {
            if (listener != null)   this.listeners.Add(listener);
        }

        public  void                Unlisten(Action<TMessage> listener)
        {
            if (listeners.Contains(listener))   this.listeners.Remove(listener);
        }

        public  void                Broadcast(TMessage message)
        {
            foreach(var listener in this.listeners) listener(message);
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeMessageType
    {
        public  int     SomeId;
        public  string  SomeDescription;
    }

    public  class   SomeOtherMessageType
    {
        public  DateTime    SomeDate;
        public  Double      SomeAmount;
    }

    public  class   SomePublisher
    {

        private PubSub<SomeMessageType> pubSub;

        public                          SomePublisher(PubSub<SomeMessageType> pubSub)   { this.pubSub = pubSub; }

        public  void                    DoSomethingCool(string description)
        {
            var randomizer  = new Random();
            this.pubSub.Broadcast(new SomeMessageType(){SomeId = randomizer.Next(), SomeDescription = description});
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeOtherPublisher
    {

        private PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>    pubSub;

        public                                  SomeOtherPublisher(PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType> pubSub) { this.pubSub = pubSub; }

        public  void    DoSomethingElse(DateTime when)
        {
            var randomizer  = new Random();
            this.pubSub.Broadcast(new SomeOtherMessageType(){SomeAmount = randomizer.NextDouble(), SomeDate = when});
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeListener
    {

        public  void    Listen(PubSub<SomeMessageType> pubSub)
        {
            pubSub.Listen(this.SomeMessageEvent);
        }

        private void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeMessageType message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attention! SomeMessageType receieved by SomeListener with\r\nid: {0}\r\ndescription: {1}\r\n", message.SomeId, message.SomeDescription);
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeOtherListener1
    {

        public  void    Listen(PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType> pubSub)
        {
            pubSub.Listen(this.SomeMessageEvent);
        }

        private void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeOtherMessageType message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Heads up! SomeOtherMessageType receieved by SomeOtherListener1 with\r\namount: {0}\r\ndate: {1}\r\n", message.SomeAmount, message.SomeDate);
        }

    }

    public  class   SomeOtherListener2
    {

        public  void    Listen(PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType> pubSub)
        {
            pubSub.Listen(this.SomeMessageEvent);
        }

        private void    SomeMessageEvent(SomeOtherMessageType message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yo! SomeOtherMessageType receieved by SomeOtherListener2 withr\namount: {0}\r\ndate: {1}\r\n", message.SomeAmount, message.SomeDate);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that works: you're storing all of the listeners in the same list (as far as I can tell). Yes, they all inherit from TMessage, but you're calling **all** listeners regardless of their actual parameter type, which would cause type conversion errors.

Comment: Actually, all listeners are not stored in the same list.  PubSub<SomeMessageType> is a different class from PubSub<SomeOtherMessageType>.  Therefore, there are two lists of listeners in memory, each containing only their own types of listeners.

This is part of the nature of how generics work.  List<int> is a different class in memory from List<string>.  PubSub<SomeMessageType>.listeners can't hold an Action<SomeOtherMessageType> anymore than List<int> can hold a string.  Try the code out for yourself.  You'll see that it works.

Comment: Another way to think of generics is like this.  When you take a generic class and supply a type argument to it, it is sort of like taking the class, copying and pasting it, replacing all instances of the generic parameter with the type argument and giving the new copy a new name.  The copy is no longer the same class as the original.  All static fields and properties are "copied" and do not share their data with other "copied" definitions of the generic class.

Comment: Ok, but this is using a static class and I want to use an instanced class.  While I **could** register all of my events at a global level, I'd rather not have to, as some of the things I'm using it for is inter-component messaging on an entity.  Every other entity doesn't need to be notified when one of them does something.

Comment: You can modify the code rather easily to be instance based instead of static based.  Remove the static from the PubSub and instantiate it instead.  You will need to provide the same PubSub instances to both publishers and listeners in order for them to share the same message queue.  Realize though that this is another level of partitioning of the listener lists and you may not end up getting the results that you expect.

Comment: I just posted an update containing a full proof of concept using the static version of this code that you can try out to see that the generics partitioning strategy works.  I hate to plug my blog, but if you want to see how the partitioning strategy is applied another way, check out this post: http://tyreejackson.com/subclassable-enums/

Comment: The subclassable enum thing is directly talking to me about one of the things I miss from Java (I learned a fair portion of skills while modding Minecraft).  Having fields on an enum has its benefits.  Anyway, I'll look over your sample code and try and digest it.

Comment: For your convenience, I've posted another update containing an instance based PubSub.  You should be able to copy and paste it into a console project and execute it.

Comment: You may also find the information in the first post of my series on Generics useful.  You can read it here http://tyreejackson.com/generics-net-part1-basics/ .  I also have part 5 up there on the use of generic namespaces (still need to write parts 2-4).

Comment: Thanks again.  I may end up using the implementation I've already got (turns out that Unity uses .NET 3.5 which doesn't support the covariance and contravariance I was looking for; the other answer which is now missing).  But this might still be useful.

Comment: FYI> The code above should work all the way down to .Net 2.0.