# Unity3D EventManager: Dictionary with Events of generic Type that derives from an interface

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

Good day,

Currently I am working on an EventSystem for an Unity Porject.
Therefore I want to make use of the UnityEvent (which have been improved during the last year as I heard).

The EventManager shall be as generic as possible and therefore register the Events by their EventType. Therefore I created a generic BaseEvent which derives from UnityEvent. The type shall be of IEventData, which is an interface for defining EventData objects.

```
public class BaseEvent<T> : UnityEvent<T> where T : IEventData {}

public interface IEventData {}

public struct SomeEventData : IEventData
{
    public readonly float someFloat;
    public readonly bool someBool;

    public SomeEventData(float param1, bool param2)
    {
        someFloat = param1;
        someBool = param2;
    }
}
```

Now I have following problems in the Eventmanager. 
As the EventManager holds a dictionary with BaseEvent I get errors when trying to access them from the generic Methods like AddListener.

```
public class EventManager {
private Dictionary<System.Type, BaseEvent<IEventData>> m_events;

private static EventManager m_instance;

public static EventManager Instance {
    get {
        if (m_instance == null) {
            m_instance = new EventManager();
        }
        return m_instance;
    }
}

public static void AddListener<T>(BaseEvent<T> listener) where T : IEventData {             
    BaseEvent<T> tempEvent;     

    if (Instance.m_events.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out tempEvent)) {
        tempEvent.AddListener(listener);
    }
    else {
        tempEvent = new BaseEvent<T>();
        tempEvent.AddListener(listener);
        Instance.m_events.Add(typeof(T), tempEvent);
    }
}
```

The error is obvious. It's not possible to convert from BaseEvent of T to out BaseEvent of IEventData. But I don't know how I have to change the code to get it working. I thought "where T : IEventData" fixes the problem, but I think it does not, as T may be a derived class.

My question is:
Is it possible to add generic BaseEvents as I intend to do it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is with covariance, which is not currently supported in the .Net subset available in Unity.

Your problem has been well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296664/avoid-passing-generic-type-parameter-of-class-extending-generic-class)

Comment: See also [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572956/understanding-generics-and-func-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code in visual studio and the error is:

```
Argument 2: can not covert from 'out BaseEvent<T>' to 'out BaseEvent<IEventData>'
```

Please include this kind of error messages next time you post your question

However, in your place I'd change the declaration of `BaseEvent<T> tempEvent;` to `BaseEvent<IEventData> tempEvent;` and that should get you going